# Vue Reactivity: Creating reactive data with provide and inject

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-reactivity

My aim is to validate a users' credentials from vue frontend, fetch their data, store the data in a globally available variable and use them in any component. After some work, I'm able to use Vue's `reactive()` method with `inject` and `provide`. Here's my current code:
In **store/index.js**

```
import { reactive, inject } from 'vue'

// global states
export const stateSymbol = Symbol('state')
export const createState = () => reactive({
    backendRoute: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/',
    currentUser: {},
    logIn: userData => {
        let user = createState.currentUser
        user = userData
        console.log(user)
    }
})

export const useState = () => inject(stateSymbol)
```

Then in **main.js**

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
// store modules
import { stateSymbol, createState } from './store'

// create app
const app = createApp(App)
app.provide(stateSymbol, createState())
```

Then in login/register component named **Login.vue**

```
import { useState } from "../store"
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
    name: 'RegisterLogin',
    setup() {
       let state = useState()
       axios.get(getUser, jwtConfig).then(response => {
                userId = response.data.id
                const currentUser = getUserProfile+userId // URL
                console.log(currentUser)
                const getCurrentUser = axios.get(currentUser, jwtConfig)
                getCurrentUser.then(response => {
                    
                    state.logIn(response.data)
                    console.log(state.currentUser)

                })
            })
    }
}
```

`console.log(user)` in **store/index.js** logs the `userData` as expected. I believe with that, `createState.currentUser` should be mutated. The problem however is `console.log(state.currentUser)` logs an empty proxy object. Also, if I try accessing the state.currentUser from another component like **Home.vue**:

```
<template>
{{ state.currentUser }}
</template>

<script>
import { useState } from '../store/'

export default {
        name: 'Index',
        setup() {

            return {
                state: useState(),
            }
        },
}
</script>
```

...an empty object is always displayed even after the user logs in successfully. Is there anything I'm doing wrong? Thank you for your assistance (in advance).

Answer (score 1):

I was looking through the code but couldn't find anywhere where the variable was getting mutated, but I believe I know what's going on.

You are reassigning the `user` object, not assigning the `createState.currentUser` to another object.

```js
import { reactive, inject } from 'vue'

// global states
export const stateSymbol = Symbol('state')
export const createState = reactive({
    backendRoute: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/',
    currentUser: {},
    logIn: userData => {
        // over here you assign user to createState.currentUser
        let user = createState.currentUser; 

        // then you reassign user to `user data`
        user = userData
        console.log(user)
    }
})

export const useState = () => inject(stateSymbol)
```

you could instead try

```js
import { reactive, inject } from 'vue'

// global states
export const stateSymbol = Symbol('state')
export const createState = () => reactive({
    backendRoute: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/',
    currentUser: {},
    logIn: userData => {
        createState.currentUser = userData
        console.log(createState.currentUser)
    }
})

export const useState = () => inject(stateSymbol)
```

As an aside, why are you using `inject`? I can't figure out what you're expecting it to do.

`export const useState = () => stateSymbol` would have the same result, but you don't even need to pass the function, you can just use something more concise like...

```js
//////// store 

import { reactive } from 'vue'

// global states
export const store = reactive({
    backendRoute: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/',
    currentUser: {}
})
export const logIn = (userData) => {
    store.currentUser = userData
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////
////// main

import { store, logIn } from "../store"
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
    name: 'RegisterLogin',
    setup() {
       axios.get(getUser, jwtConfig).then(response => {
                userId = response.data.id
                const currentUser = getUserProfile+userId // URL
                console.log(currentUser)
                const getCurrentUser = axios.get(currentUser, jwtConfig)
                getCurrentUser.then(response => {
                    logIn(response.data)
                    console.log(store.currentUser)
                })
            })
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I had previously tried the approach of assigning `userData` to `createState.currentUser` and I got the same result. As for why I'm using `inject`, I'm trying to create a centralized state without using Vuex because I find Vuex to be overly complicated. [https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-provide-inject.html] According to official doc, I can use `inject` and `provide` to share data among child components. Everything seems to work until I try to mutate `state.currentUser` globally.

Comment: you don't need `provide/inject` for that. There are use cases for it, but if you just import the store (`import { store } from "../store"`), it is accessible from anywhere.

Comment: @Daniel I used your explanation to create a global object. The problem is that I have to refresh the page to get the object. See more details here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65950533/10123373

Comment: I am also facing the similar problem right now. As for as I know, we can address this problem with provide / inject pattern. But the reactivity is not reflecting even in my code. Something went weird and I am not able to find myself.

Answer (score 0):

It appears @Daniel was right after all. My `logIn` method in *store/index.js* was not really mutating the `currentUser` property. In fact, I'm unable to access that property from the method. To solve this, I had to do the mutation immediately after the axios call like `state.currentUser = response.data` in `then` method and boom, the state is updated in all components! Thanks.